# Stuck on scrumptious tutorial, how to get an "active access token"?

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, oauth

The title pretty much sums it up, i am trying to test my Open Graph Actions in the Graph API Explorer but when i POST to /me/mynamespace:myaction, i get this error (Using the access token the Graph API Explorer generated for me, i asked for publish_actions only)

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#15) This method must be called with an app access_token.", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 15
  }
}
```

Ive done my homework and searched about it, to find a proper access-token to solve this problem goes by the APPID|APP_SECRET format but using that i get

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 2500
  }
}
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?

To give out more context the graph actions were created for an android facebook app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't post to `/me` without a user access token from a user who's logged into your app, 'me' is a placeholder for 'current user'.

It sounds like two things have happened here:

1. You've configured the Open Graph action to require the App Access Token to post (which is a configuration option on the action
2. When you came across that error, you tried to use the App Access Token but didnt' change `/me/mynamespace:myaction` to `/<USER ID>/mynamespace:myaction`

Some notes:

- Never put the app access token into your client code; it can be used to modify app settings. If you really need actions to only be postable via the app access token, you'll need to implement a server-side component to your app which makes the requests with the app access token
- You probably need to change the open graph action settings for your action so it can be posted with a user access token

Comment: You sir have won a handful of internets. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your method of sending `APP_ID|SECRET` as an app access token is wrong. To get an app access token, you need to request it via this endpoint:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID
   &client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET&grant_type=client_credentials
```

See [here for more details](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/login-as-app/)

Comment: Still, i am getting the same 2500 OAuth Exception trying to POST to /me

Comment: The `oauth/access_token` endpoint is the recommended way to retrieve an app access token but currently `<APP ID>|<APP SECRET>` will work too